# WinApi change font charset

Tags: winapi

I get Windows font by calling GetStockObject API. Then before drawing by GDI+ I need to change this font charset (or to create a copy of it with changed charset). What are the ways to impelement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://www.suite101.com/content/win32-easy-font-handling-tutorial-a33586) may help explain now to modify an existing system font.  You'd just need to set your alternate charset in your call to `CreateFontIndirect()`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows fonts are generally based on Unicode. They don't use charsets.

Also, this sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: There is charset parameter for CreateFont function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183499(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That's a historical thing, mostly. `CreateFont` dates back to Windows 3 (if not older) which was not Unicode-aware. [Microsoft says it's now ignored](http://www.ureader.com/msg/1473279.aspx)